# Where can tactical maps for battles of the Mexican Revolution be accessed?

Tags: battle, mexico, tactics, resource, reference

There are a bunch of resources on the Mexican revolution, but I've never seen an academical text that narrates the major battles in the struggle along with tactical maps.

Thus, I'm looking for a resource on tactical maps of the major battles in the Mexican revolution. In particular, I am interested in the battle of Zacatecas city in 1914. If anyone know this, feel free to answer.

Sources does not need to be in English.

Comment: Requests for sources are generally frowned upon, but I think this one is on-topic as it can be definitively answered.

Comment: Osprey's Elite 137, 'The Mexican Revolution' has a map which features the locations of the battles but no tactical maps. Otherwise, though, you should include where and what you've already investigated.

Comment: Not seeing anything online but plenty of books which might potentially have something, so agreed with above, if you've looked at any relevant books already a list would be helpful.

Comment: @gktscrk thanks for the reference I didn't know it. If you know in particular the details of the Zacatecas battle I mentioned please write an answer :).

Comment: Have you tried to contact SEDENA and their military academy?

Comment: No, I'm afraid I don't have any other details. If you want, I can answer with a strategic map of the battles of the war (but no tactical dispositions), but I don't think that will be massively helpful for your purpose.

Comment: Maybe it is worth to check with the Archivo General de la Nación
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archivo_General_de_la_Naci%C3%B3n_(Mexico)